# What is the minimum of EOS I need when creating a brand new account?

Tags: tokens, requirements

Is there some type of EOS minimum to have in an account when creating a new eos account? Say I wanted to create one just to receive a bunch of different tokens. Do these tokens take up ram space? And if I wanted to send these tokens back out, how much eos do I really need in my account as there are no fees, but required to just hold eos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least 5~6 kbyte of ram, with a little bit of CPU,NET

for just holding an EOS, 0.1EOS with CPU and 0.01EOS with NET is sufficient.

currentlyl, 6kbyte RAM costs about 0.6 EOS

hence, 0.7 EOS($ 3.85) would be suitable

Comment: EOSlynx app generate you the eos account for 1$, they are support for cheaper resource in generating account as a promotion. Try this

Comment: Do you have to stake the .1EOS for cpu or net when your holding the .1? So what your saying you *MUST* have some eos in your account in order to use the network? what happens if you have ZERO eos?

Comment: for creating account, resource is essential. If some one withdraw all resources in his account after create it, account will be halt. Nothing of actions(transfer, delegate.. ) won't be work