# How much does it cost to create a new account, which only needs to hold token balances?

Tags: ram, tokens, cpu, net

Assuming the new account won't be performing any actions, what is the bare minimum of EOS required to create the new account?

- How much RAM?
- How much CPU/NET needs to be staked/delegated?

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/what-is-the-minimum-of-eos-i-need-when-creating-a-brand-new-account
However, I'd like a more detailed/verbose answer, for accounts which only need to hold token balances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v1.5.1 an account that won't perform any action (including transfer) you don't need to delegate CPU/NET. Bare minimum amount for new account is 3 kbytes with the current reward for newaccount which is 1.5 kb ([article from Dan](https://medium.com/@bytemaster/a-three-step-plan-for-lowering-eos-account-creation-costs-c3bf1ec736b7)). Which require the creator to buy 1608 bytes.

```
--stake-net="0.0000 EOS" --stake-cpu="0.0000 EOS" --buy-ram-bytes=1608
```

Results:

```
RAM used 2996 bytes / quota: 1596 bytes
```

In this state, the account can receive EOS, but cannot transfer it back. You can always delegate sufficient amount of bandwidth to make the account functioning.